google sign in pop up appears two times
when i click on in sign in  it appears two time, first pop up give me log (handleCredentialResponse called) . and the second pop up do rest of the work really frusted with this bug.


<!-- Google Identity Services Library and Initialization Script -->
<script>
  (function () {
    // Check if Google Sign-In has already been initialized
    if (window.googleSignInInitialized) {
      console.log("Google Sign-In has already been initialized.");
      return;
    }

    // Set a flag to indicate initialization has started
    window.googleSignInInitialized = true;

    // Function to initialize Google Sign-In
    function initializeGoogleSignIn() {
      console.log("Initializing Google Sign-In.");

      // Replace these placeholders with your actual values
      const GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = "XXXX"; // Your Google OAuth Client ID
      const CLOUD_RUN_BASE_URL = "XXXX"; // Your Cloud Run service URL

      /**
       * Function to handle credential response from Google Sign-In
       * @param {Object} response - The credential response from Google
       */
      function handleCredentialResponse(response) {
        console.log("handleCredentialResponse called.");
        // Extract the ID token from the response
        const idToken = response.credential;

        // Initialize the token client to request an OAuth access token
        const tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
          client_id: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
          scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage",
          prompt: "", // No prompt to avoid additional pop-ups
          callback: (tokenResponse) => {
            if (tokenResponse.error) {
              console.error(
                "Error obtaining access token:",
                tokenResponse.error
              );
              return;
            }

            const accessToken = tokenResponse.access_token;
            console.log("Access Token:", accessToken);

            // Optionally, you can verify the ID token if needed
            fetch(`https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token=${idToken}`)
              .then((res) => res.json())
              .then((data) => {
                if (data.email) {
                  const email = data.email;
                  const name = data.name || "No Name Provided";
                  console.log("User Email:", email);
                  console.log("User Name:", name);

                  // Start the data processing flow
                  processUserData(email, name, accessToken);
                } else {
                  console.error("Unable to retrieve user information.");
                }
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                console.error("Error verifying ID token:", err);
              });
          },
        });

        // Request the OAuth access token
        tokenClient.requestAccessToken();
      }

      /**
       * Function to process user data by fetching Google Business ID and storing data in Airtable
       * @param {string} email - User's email
       * @param {string} name - User's name
       * @param {string} accessToken - OAuth access token
       */
      function processUserData(email, name, accessToken) {
        console.log("Processing user data...");

        // Step 1: Fetch Google Business ID
        fetch(`${CLOUD_RUN_BASE_URL}/fetch-google-business-id`, {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        })
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((accountData) => {
            if (accountData.accounts && accountData.accounts.length > 0) {
              const googleBusinessId = accountData.accounts[0].name;
              console.log("Google Business ID:", googleBusinessId); // Log Business ID

              // Step 2: Store data in Airtable
              storeUserData(email, name, googleBusinessId, accessToken);
            } else {
              console.error("No Google Business accounts found.");
            }
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error fetching Google Business ID:", error);
          });
      }

      /**
       * Function to store user data in Airtable via backend
       * @param {string} email - User's email
       * @param {string} name - User's name
       * @param {string} googleBusinessId - Google Business ID
       * @param {string} accessToken - OAuth access token
       */
      function storeUserData(email, name, googleBusinessId, accessToken) {
        console.log("Storing user data in Airtable...");

        fetch(`${CLOUD_RUN_BASE_URL}/store-user-data`, {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ email, name, googleBusinessId }),
        })
          .then((response) => {
            if (!response.ok) {
              return response.json().then((errData) => {
                throw new Error(errData.error || "Unknown error occurred.");
              });
            }
            return response.json();
          })
          .then((data) => {
            console.log("Data stored in Airtable:", data);
            // Optional: You can add more actions here, such as redirecting the user
            // window.location.href = '/welcome';
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error storing data in Airtable:", error);
          });
      }

      /**
       * Initialize the Google Sign-In button
       */
      google.accounts.id.initialize({
        client_id: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        callback: handleCredentialResponse,
        cancel_on_tap_outside: false,
      });

      google.accounts.id.renderButton(
        document.getElementById("g_id_signin"),
        { theme: "outline", size: "large", type: "standard" } // Customization options
      );

      // Optional: Automatically prompt the user to sign in
      google.accounts.id.prompt();
    }

    // Function to wait until the Google library is loaded
    function waitForGoogleLibrary(callback) {
      if (
        typeof google !== "undefined" &&
        google.accounts &&
        google.accounts.id
      ) {
        callback();
      } else {
        setTimeout(() => waitForGoogleLibrary(callback), 100);
      }
    }

    // Initialize Google Sign-In once the library is loaded
    waitForGoogleLibrary(initializeGoogleSignIn);
  })();
</script>



i have tried to change the code but nothing  work also search in google nothing works. i also check chatgpt but could not find the bug. please help

Looks like you are first rendering a login button with google.accounts.id.renderButton(...) - and then you trigger automatic login right after that? // Optional: Automatically prompt the user to sign in
